# Does column deletion make lastModifiedDateTime change?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list

As per the title, I want to use the `lastModifiedDateTime` field from a Graph API request to keep track of the state of a list.

If a user deletes an entry from the list, does the field get updated, or it does only happen when an *existing* row gets edited?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just did a test in my environment, the column deletion will make lastModifiedDateTime change in Graph API.